# I want to downgrade my protobuf version in order to working with gcc-4.9 and matlab. so have anybody can taking a good solution?

Tags: installation, protocol-buffers

```
xy@xy-desktop:/usr/bin$ sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libprotobuf-dev is already the newest version (2.6.1-1.3).
protobuf-compiler is already the newest version (2.6.1-1.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 361 not upgraded.

xy@xy-desktop:/usr/bin$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.0.2
```

Comment: why i have two kind of protobuf version?one is 2.6 and other is 3.0.2

Comment: Is it possible you have two copies installed, once installed from source and one installed using apt-get?

Comment: yep , i want to know how fix it if i want to downgrade my protobuf version?

Comment: You need to uninstall the newer one. If you installed it from source using `make install`, then go back to the source code directory and do `make uninstall`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have installed protobuf 3.0.2 from some external source whose binary is probably in /usr/local/bin, while the protobuf 2.6.1 installed from repo has its binary in /usr/bin. Try this:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
protoc --version
```

Whenever you want to go back to using protobuf 3.0.2, just ensure that /usr/local/bin is at the left side in PATH environment variable.

Please note that this may also have similar effect on other binaries which are present in both /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin (for the current terminal session).

A permanent solution to this would entail uninstalling protobuf 3.0.2, by running

```
sudo make uninstall
```

in the source folder of protobuf 3.0.2.