# How to downgrade libprotobuf.so

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm trying to run a .pyc which shows this msg:

**ImportError: libprotobuf.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

I have a newer version of libprotobuf.

Do you know how to solve this issue? I think the only way is to downgrade libprotobuf. But how can I do that and install the exact version it is asking me for?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to downgrade my protobuf version in order to working with gcc-4.9 and matlab. so have anybody can taking a good solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45895931/i-want-to-downgrade-my-protobuf-version-in-order-to-working-with-gcc-4-9-and-mat)

Answer (score 1):

My ubuntu 18.04 had a same problem and I solved it as follows.
Here are different version libprotobuf
(https://pkgs.org/download/libprotobuf)

`$ sudo apt-get update`

`$ sudo apt-get install gdebi`

`$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/protobuf/libprotobuf9v5_2.6.1-1.3_amd64.deb`

`$ sudo gdebi ./libprotobuf9v5_2.6.1-1.3_amd64.deb`

You can use gdebi to install this deb package solving dependencies.